# insertion of system date and time into mysql table in their respective fields

Tags: mysql

i am not new to php but facing a problem of very basic level but dont know how to overcome it. i have a table for comments in which fields are name ,email, comment, date and time. now what i want to do is to insert system date and time in their respective fields but it only enters time not date. the types of field date is date and of time is time.
 here is my query

```
 $insert = 'insert into tbl_comment 
      (name, email, desc, date, time)
      VALUES 
 ("'.$_POST['name'].'","'.$_POST['email'].'","'.$_POST['comment'].'"
 ,CURDATE(),"CURTIME()",CURTIME())';   
      mysql_query($insert);
 }
```

plz help me out

Comment: why you have date and time as different column? one column with data type as datetime or timestamp would have done...

Comment: infact i need them separate according to the requirments of client

Answer (score 0):

**Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. [Fix this immediately!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)**

```
//Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

$myName = clean($_POST['name']);
$myEmail = clean($_POST['email']);
$myDesc = clean($_POST['comment']);
$insert = "insert into tbl_comment 
           (name, email, desc, `date`, `time`)
           VALUES 
           ('$myName','$myEmail','$myDesc',CURDATE(),CURTIME())";   
mysql_query($insert);
```

If you have **data & time** as field name, use backticks as they are reserved keywords.

Also read, ***[how to insert data in PHP/ MySQL](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)***

Comment: i tried this as well before but it also not working i dont know why

Comment: @KashifWaheed : What error are you getting? Also see my updated answer with backticks...

Comment: dear the resulting query is wrong and once query is wrong then its impossible to insert data into the table thats the error

Comment: @KashifWaheed : can u type `echo $insert` before mysql_query and let me know what you get?

Comment: @KashifWaheed :  also are you using backticks ` as I suggested??